# A for loop needs to run LLONG_MAX times, but the counter variable needs to also represent signed numbers. What type do you use for the counter?

Tags: c++

I'm hoping you can entertain this hypothetical question even though this has probably never been a problem for anyone ever.

I used to write my for loops like

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < container.size(); ++i)
```

to avoid the warnings related to comparing a signed and unsigned, but after being bitten a few too many times trying to involve `i` in operations that resulted in negative numbers, I started writing them like this, casting the size to int to also avoid that warning:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (int)container.size(); ++i)
```

---

Now lets say that there's a case where `container.size() > INT_MAX` and in the loop we have something like.

```
for (int i = 0; i < (int)container.size(); ++i) {
  size_t x = 0;
  while (i - x++ > INT_MIN) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

We need `i` to be signed, but we also need `i` to be able to represent a number larger than `INT_MAX`. I know that the super simple answer here to use `long`, but then the same problem arises eventually even if you use `long long` if you have to run your loop `> LLONG_MAX` times.

In this case, you would finally be forced into using an unsigned type for your counter variable capable of representing a number that large, but you would still need to be able to check this condition

```
while (i - x++ > LLONG_MIN)
```

how do you do it? (given you actually have some reason to run a loop 9 quintillion times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most containers have a `size_type` typedef to specify the data type that is used for indexes and sizes within the container.  For example, if `container` is a `std::vector`, you would use `std::vector::size_type` instead of `int` or even `size_t`:

```
for (std::vector<type>::size_type i = 0; i < container.size(); ++i)
{
    // use container[i] as needed
}
```

An alternative solution is to use iterators instead of indexes, then you don't need to worry about any counter data type at all:

```
for (std::vector<type>::iterator iter = container.begin(); iter != container.end(); ++iter)
{
    // use *iter as needed
}
```

Which can be simplified using `auto` in C++11 and later:

```
for (auto iter = container.begin(); iter != container.end(); ++iter)
{
    // use *iter as needed
}
```

---

Your inner `while` loop doesn't really make any sense to me, but if you really need something like `INT_MIN` for a container, you can use [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) to get the min/max values of the container's `size_type`, eg:

```
typedef std::vector<type>::size_type container_size_type;

for (container_size_type i = 0; i < container.size(); ++i) {
    container_size_type x = 0;
    while ((i - x++) > std::numeric_lists<container_size_type>::min()) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

It seems it would be easier to just loop between the two indexes instead:

```
typedef std::vector<type>::size_type container_size_type;

for (container_size_type i = 0; i < container.size(); ++i) {
    for (container_size_type j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Or:

```
typedef std::vector<type>::size_type container_size_type;

for (container_size_type i = 0; i < container.size(); ++i) {
    for (container_size_type j = i; j >= 0; --j) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Depending on which direction you want the inner loop to run.

However, either of those loops can be re-written using iterators as well (replace 'auto' with the appropriate type if you are not using C++11), eg:

```
for (auto iter = container.begin(); iter != container.end(); ++iter) {
    for (auto iter2 = container.begin(); iter2 != iter; ++iter2) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

```
for (auto iter = container.begin(); iter != container.end(); ++iter) {
    for (auto iter2 = std::vector<type>::reverse_iterator(iter); iter2 != container.rend(); ++iter2) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow the `size_type` was exactly what I was hoping existed.

Comment: I might have accepted a bit too quickly though because `size_type` is still unsigned right? Also iterators make a lot of sense, but they don't satisfy my contrived while loop. The more I think about it though...the dumber this question gets in the practical world.

Comment: While I fully agree that this is how stl containers should be used, isn't this answer missing the point of the question because those container size types are an alias to some fundamental type, so the problem persists?

Comment: You can use `std::numeric_limits` to get the min and max values of a given data type.  You can use the container's `size_type` as the numeric type.

Comment: Great answer even with my dumb constraints. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess a reasonable approach would be to use some [bignum library](http://www.ttmath.org/). A less reasonable, but probably more interesting approach would be to implement what's needed on your own.

Comment: Lol I was hoping that there was some option I hadn't thought of other than "use a type that holds even bigger numbers".

Comment: I'm interested in some bit-fiddling answer as well, but will probably see it as an academic exercise rather than something I'd do in "my" code. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you really had a need to execute such a thing its likely that you care about the execution time because its going to take forever.  At that point you have to look at something like intel's AVX, which now supports up to 512 bit numbers.  In practical terms, 64 bits is almost always big enough for a loop because I seriously doubt anything that takes 2^64 (1.8e19) cycles to finish is ever going to complete in your life time because there are only about 3e18 nano seconds in a human life time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library that can handle and compare large numbers. Or you can add another variable that will represent how many time you reached max number.

for example:

```
long i = 0;
long t = 0;
while (true) {

    // DO your thing.

    if (i >= 2000000000) {
        i = 0;
        ++t;
        if (t >= 2000000000)
            break;
    }
}
```

Or using a for loop

```
for (long i = 0; i < 2000000000; ++i)
        for (long j = 0; j < 2000000000; ++j) {

            // Do your thing
        }
```

This way you will loop i * j times.